# How to create a 'star' system for a resource and write conditions based on the association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a Ruby on Rails application (2.3.9) where users can record workouts. I am trying to implement a 'star' system which would allow a logged_in user to star workouts from other users that they want to remember.

I am doing this by creating a `Star` resource (associations below). I am successfully creating a deleting records in my `Star` table and now want to conditionally display view code based on if a current_user has already starred a workout.

I am displaying all workouts through a partial for _workouts.html.erb. For each workout, I would like to either display the `<% remote_form_for [workout, Star.new]...` or `You have already starred this workout`.

```
Workout :has_many => :stars

User :has_many => :stars

Star :belongs_to => :workouts
Star :belongs_to => :users
```

I imagine I will have to create a named_scope in Star.rb that looks to see if if there is an existing star record where the workout_id matches workout.id and where current_user.id matches the star.user_id match for that workout. It confuses me just typing this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `has_many ..., :through => ...` relationship, and then use `#include?` to check for an association.

```
# User
has_many :starred_workouts, :class_name => 'Workout', :through => :stars

# View
<% if current_user.starred_workouts.include? workout %>
    ...
```